# Generalization of Sequences of Group Operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, group-theory, soft-question

In analysis, we see infinite sums everywhere. In "nice" spaces, these sums converge when the individual terms converge to the additive identity element, namely, $0$. We also see infinite products whose convergence is classified when the individual elements converge to the multiplicative identity, namely,
$1$.

**My question is**; Does there exist a generalization of this property given some group and an infinite sequence of group elements?

I never took more than $2$ algebra classes and my background is in a different field entirely so please take it easy on me lol. But feel free to give technical explanations and examples! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even in the real numbers, it isn't true that an infinite sum converges if the terms go to $0$, sadly.  For an abstract group, there is no notion of limit, so infinite sums and products are not generally defined.  In topological groups there are things one can do.

Comment: @lulu thank you! I know we can have "sequences" of open sets, is there a topological group example you can think of though?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb R^n$ of course.  Or a torus (quotient of $\mathbb R^n$ by a lattice).  And matrix groups.  We can define $\exp(M)$ for a matrix $M$ via a power series, as we do for real numbers, so that's an infinite series in a non-abelian group.  Keep in mind, of course, that matrices need not commute with each other.